# Hooking the_content filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm saving the post content into a post meta, and I'd like to retrieve it instead of the original post content so that when I call the_content() the data in the post meta appears not the actual post data.

```
function test(){
    $post_meta = post meta data here ....
    echo apply_filters('the_content', '$post_meta');
}
add_filter('the_content', 'test');
```

I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached
```

The error does make sense, but how can I achieve what I'm trying to do, any ideas?

Comment: Change 'echo' to 'return'. What happens then?

Comment: Nothing, still the same error.

Comment: Then change 'echo apply_filters('the_content', '$post_meta');' to 'return $post_meta;'.

Comment: Doing this will produce a raw data from the database, I wan't to apply the_content filter on the data and then hook the result to the_content function

Comment: Problem is, you're calling 'the_content' every time apply_filter('the_content') is run, and you've added a filter to 'the_content' that runs an apply_filter('the_content'). test() is being run recursively because of this. Why not apply a custom filter to format the post meta how you need?

Comment: The post meta holds a data that was entered by a second rich editor, so it contains images, shortcodes, and formatted text. I need to display the data of this post meta just like the data displayed with the_content :) That's the problem

Comment: Agreed, that is quite the pickle. However, you still can't apply a 'the_content' filter from within an added 'the_content' filter without being caught in an infinite loop. Looking into some solutions for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** After much banging my head against the wall, here is the best way I can think of to hook into the_content and use its filter from within the custom callback without falling into an infinite loop.

The answer was surprisingly simple, and I feel silly for not thinking of it before:

```
function test($content)
{
    remove_action('the_content', 'test'); //DISABLE THE CUSTOM ACTION
    $post_meta = post meta data here ....
    $cleaned_meta = apply_filters('the_content', $post_meta);
    add_action('the_content', 'test'); //REENABLE FROM WITHIN
    return $cleaned_meta;
}
add_action('the_content', 'test');
```

I'm sure you've found another solution by now, but still, I hope this helps with any issues you might run into in the future.

Comment: When I use get_the_content() it returns the original content not the post meta :D

Comment: I this I'll use a custom function and apply the_content() filter to it instead of using the content

Comment: Interesting. Sorry I couldn't help you more. Let me know how it all turns out.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll let you know if I came to a solution

Comment: @MohamedSaid I know it's late, but please review my updated answer. Hopefully this can help in the future.

Comment: WOW I actually did something different, I made a check for all the Filters applied to the_content, applied all of it again and hook my function to the_content. But of course Your solution is better :) Thanks So Much.

Comment: Anytime. I'm glad this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add your filter before `the_content()` is even called. You probably want something like this.

```
function modify_content() {
    global $post;
    $post_meta = 'testing';
    $post->post_content = $post_meta;
}
add_action('wp_head', 'modify_content');
```

This would allow you to modify the contents of the post and still run it through the filters on `the_content()`. Though this will only work for single posts/pages. You will have to find another hook if you want to alter the archive pages too.