# How to limit string to some character in php

Tags: php

I have a php code which displays description of each post in main page(www.kushaku.com):
Below is the code which displays description:

```
   <p class="shortdesc1">
     <?php the_content(); ?> 
   </p>
```

I am tryin to limit the description part of main page to some characters, say 180 characters, and after that display '...'

I tried below code:

```
  function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
 {
   $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
   if(count($words) > $word_limit) {
   array_pop($words);
   //add a ... at last article when more than limit word count
   echo implode(' ', $words)."..."; } else {
   //otherwise
   echo implode(' ', $words); }
 }




 <?php
   $excerpt = the_content();
   echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25);
 ?>
```

but it is still showing full content.
If i print count($words), it is showing '1', 
if i take strlen of $string, it gives me output as '0'.
If i use count_chars() it gives me output as '0'.

Please suggest any way to achieve my objective.

Thanks in Advance,
Vivek

Comment: Why not make use of `substr()` ?

Comment: yes this is wordpress

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, because he definitely wants to end up on witespace, not just 180th char

Comment: @vladkras, `substr()` would work just fine. and OP doesn't want the whitespace at the end. He wants the `....` followed by the 180th character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`the_content()` will *output* the content into the page. It does not `return`, it *`echo`s*. I believe to get the content in a variable you need to use `get_the_content()`.

This is only my passing knowledge of Wordpress though, I'd be really surprised if there wasn't such an excerpt function already built in.

Comment: Thanks mate, you are a life savior, i am new to wordpress, using get_the_content(), i am getting correct output. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I think `substr` is function is something you need.

```
$a = "this is test description";

echo substr($a, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `substr` you can obtain a string (1st parm) starting form (2nd parm) of the length you specify (3rd parm). So something like this:

```
$excerpt = "Hi I'm a string";

function string_limit_words($str, $limit)
{
    return substr($str, 0, $limit) . '...';
}

echo string_limit_words($excerpt, 10);
```

**Seeing that you're using Wordpress** I think exists `the_excerpt()` function to get the excerpt instead of using `the_content()`. I don't know the length of chars that `the_excerpt()` returns.

Anyway you then need to use you own function in case you want to specify a different length of the excerpt

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as that:

```
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 180) . '...';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function limit_string($str, $limit){
    return strlen($str)>$limit ?  substr($str,0,$limit)."..." : $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
    $words = explode(" ", $string);
    // get 1st word length
    $count = strlen($words[0]);
    $i = 0;
    $arr = array();
    // while total length is less then limit (you can add +$i to count whitespaces too)
    while ($count < $word_limit) {
            // add word to result
        $arr[] = $words[$i];
        $count += strlen($words[$i+1]);
        $i++;
    }
    return implode(" ", $arr)." ...";
}

$string = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit';
echo string_limit_words($string, 30);
```

this function stops on word end before reaching word limit, not cutting the wo...

[**phpfiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/fi5-wga)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
    $string = substr($string, 0, $word_limit);
    if (($i = strrpos($string, ' ')) !== false) $string = substr($string, 0, $i);
    return preg_match('/^(.+\w)[.,;]?\s*$/', $string, $arr)? $arr[1] : $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several approaches on how to trim your content were posted here already so I won't post another function or snippet here.

But what is **missing** to make your function work with wordpress is that you have to add your new function as a filter for `the_content`.

Just search for "wordpress the_content hook" or see e. g. [Hooking the_content filter in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523968/hooking-the-content-filter-in-wordpress)

Cheers!